# Repaint method isnt repainting view

Tags: java, swing

So guys this is my PlayView

```
public class PlayView extends JPanel {  

TagMan tagMan;

public PlayView() {
    this.setFocusable(true);
    setupPane();
    tagMan = new TagMan();
}

public void setupPane() {
    this.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(1100,800) );
    Color colorBlueBack = Color.decode("#000332");
    this.setBackground(colorBlueBack);
}

//paint tagman
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(tagMan.getXPosition(), tagMan.getYPosition(), tagMan.getSize(), tagMan.getSize()));
}
```

}

and this is my controller class,
public class GameController extends KeyAdapter {

```
// Controllers
private MainController mainController;

// Views
private GameView gameView;
private PlayView playView;

// Models
private Game game;

public GameController(GameView gameView, PlayView playView, MainController mainController) {
    this.gameView = gameView;
    this.playView = playView;
    this.mainController = mainController;

    game = new Game();

    playView.addKeyListener(this);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        game.getTagMan().moveRight();
        System.out.println("RIGHT: " + game.getTagMan().getXPosition());
    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        game.getTagMan().moveUp();
        System.out.println("UP: " + game.getTagMan().getYPosition());
    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        game.getTagMan().moveDown();
        System.out.println("DOWN: " + game.getTagMan().getYPosition());
    }
    playView.repaint();

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

So I tried to repaint the object everytime a button is pressed. But it does not move..? What do I miss. The action changes the tagMan values and is printed correctly in the system output. I am litteraly trying it for 4 hours now but can not find the right solution to this.

Comment: Don't use `KeyListener`, use the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), it will solve the focus related issues and you won't have to hack your brains out trying to make it work

Comment: Also, you're creating a new instance of `TagMan` in `PlayView` which doesn't seem to have any relationship to the instance that `GameView` "seems" to be using. Why would `MainController` require a reference to another instance of `MainController`?  Seems like a you're digging yourself into a dangerous hole

Comment: Yes but I must use a KeyListener, and may not use the key bindings API man.

Comment: And btw the keylistenere is working right, it is that the paint isnt repainting..

Comment: KeyListener is fragile and easily broken - it’s not “painting” because you’re creating a bunch of objects which have no relationship with each but are expecting it to magically work some how.

Comment: Please post [mcve]

Comment: @MohammedAliCelik Beside the missing [mcve] (specially your `Game` class is missing), how often do you have the statement `new TagMan();` in your whole code?